# Change query column name to variable in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I use the django framework to do my task, I want to optimize my code in the template file. Here is my code blow.

```
            {% ifequal name 'jack' %}
              {% ifequal item.jack 'lower' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="lower">風險比較低</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="lower">風險比較低</button>
              {% endifequal %}
              {% ifequal item.jack 'higher' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="higher">風險比較高</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="higher">風險比較高</button>
              {% endifequal %}
              {% ifequal item.jack 'unknown' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="unknown">無法判斷</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="unknown">無法判斷</button>
              {% endifequal %}
            {% endifequal %}


            {% ifequal name 'du01' %}
              {% ifequal item.du01 'lower' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="lower">風險比較低</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="lower">風險比較低</button>
              {% endifequal %}
              {% ifequal item.du01 'higher' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="higher">風險比較高</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="higher">風險比較高</button>
              {% endifequal %}
              {% ifequal item.du01 'unknown' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="unknown">無法判斷</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="unknown">無法判斷</button>
              {% endifequal %}
            {% endifequal %}
```

I want to show button depend on different `name`.
The `name` is a variable now.
However, it map to column name in the table. Is it possible to do something like blow for clear my code?

```
              {% ifequal item.{{name}} 'lower' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="lower">風險比較低</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="lower">風險比較低</button>
              {% endifequal %}
              {% ifequal item.{{name}} 'higher' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="higher">風險比較高</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="higher">風險比較高</button>
              {% endifequal %}
              {% ifequal item.{{name}} 'unknown' %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary active" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="unknown">無法判斷</button>
              {% else %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-outline-primary" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom:100px; margin-height:120;" name="label" value="unknown">無法判斷</button>
              {% endifequal %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. What you can do is change the item object to a dictionary instead.

Then you can look up the dictionary value in the template